# Produce a Sound Notification When a User Completes a Task in a To-Do List and marks it as Completed

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, notifications

Front-end Development newbie here!

I am working on an HTML, CSS & JS To-Do list app.

When a user has marked a task as completed, I'd like the app to play a "Success" notification (.mp3 or other widely used formats).

I'd also like them to be able to turn this sound off or change the particular sound .mp3 to one they like most (from a list of preloaded .mp3s - Pretty much like the way you can choose which ringtone to use for your phone).

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, please could you include a snippet of the code you have so far. Investigate the HTML audio  tag and if you are still stuck describe what happens. Thanks. See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help in doing this.

Comment: Can you please provide us something that you tried and got error in SO we can't just give suggestions or something we are here to help you solve your problems faced in code !

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AHaworth, for pointing out the Minimum Reproducible Example. Thanks to helpful contributors like you, I'm gradually getting the hang of StackOverflow. I'll include some code to make my question clearer next time.